# 40000/40002 error in hive query using union all

Tags: sql, hive

This is a query that ran in hive 0.1.3  :

```
select 
     subquery.1
     subquery.2

from (
     select ... from ... group by ... order by ... limit 10
     union all
     select ... from ... group by ... order by ... limit 10
) subquery
```

But this error occurs in 3.x.

```
SQL Error [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 34:0 mismatched input 'union' expecting ) near '10' in subquery source
```

It works if order by and limit are removed. However, order by is necessary in logic.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`Order by limit`  wont work like this - you have to wrap them in a subquery.

```
select 
...

from (
     select * from (select ... from ... group by ... order by ... limit 10) sq1
     union all
     select * from (select ... from ... group by ... order by ... limit 10) sq2
) subquery
```

But this won't ensure result will be ordered by the way you want. So here is something you need to ensuere you get SQ1 and the SQ2 in order.

```
select 
...

from (
     select 1 ord,sq1.* from (select ... from ... group by ... order by ... limit 10) sq1
     union all
     select 2 ord,sq2.* from (select ... from ... group by ... order by ... limit 10) sq2
) subquery
order by ord -- ensures your order from UNION is maintained
```